# Replace "NaT" with next date based on previous date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, replace

My DF looks like below:

```
column1      column2
2020-11-01   1
2020-12-01   2
2021-01-01   3
NaT          4
NaT          5
NaT          6
```

Output should be like this:

```
column1      column2
2020-11-01   1
2020-12-01   2
2021-01-01   3
2021-02-01   4
2021-03-01   5
2021-04-01   6
```

I can't create next date (only months and years changed) based on the last existing date in df. Is there any pythonic way to do this? Thanks for any help!

Regards
Tomasz

Comment: Are the dates always evenly spaced as in the example (consecutive months)?

Comment: Yes, they are  evenly spaced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do it, you could probably tidy this up into more of a one liner but this will help illustrate the process a little more.

```
#convert to date
df['column1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['column1'], format='%Y-%d-%m')

#create a group for each missing section 
df['temp'] = df.column1.fillna(method = 'ffill')

#count the row within this group
df['temp2'] = df.groupby(['temp']).cumcount()

# add month
df['column1'] = [x + pd.DateOffset(months=y) for x,y in zip(df['temp'], df['temp2'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

pandas supports [time series data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html)

```py
pd.date_range("2020-11-1", freq=pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(months=1), periods=10)
```

will give

```py
DatetimeIndex(['2020-11-01', '2020-12-01', '2021-01-01', '2021-02-01',
               '2021-03-01', '2021-04-01', '2021-05-01', '2021-06-01',
               '2021-07-01', '2021-08-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='<DateOffset: months=1>')
```

Comment: Thanks for help, Ok, but what in case when I don't know the date of the first cell?

Comment: use `df.iloc[0,0]` to get first date